# Lookup exchanged data between PHP and Flash

Tags: php, flash

I'ld like to see the data that is exchanged between a Flash based web app and PHP. What is the tool of choice for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler is a great tool for sniffing HTTP requests. You can download it [here](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Also, Google Chrome's Developer section (shortcut : `ctrl + shift + j`) has a `Network` Tab, which gives you info about time and http request. It is not as detailed as fiddler though!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Charles, http://www.charlesproxy.com, it is a stand alone application instead of a browser extension, wich has some advantages. It can also presents XML, JSON and AMF in a structured way that is easy to read.